# How to differentiate Basic/Premium plan users for premium-only features in Django REST?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, stripe-payments

I am working on a beta-stage writing tool SaaS that is built with NextJS, React, and Django REST. As I’m gaining some user base, I am starting to research on introducing a premium plan to the mix using Stripe.

As most other SaaSs, I will have a subscription-based premium plan which grants access to premium-only features. However, even after days of research, I am still lost how this is commonly implemented in Django/Backend. Here is what I’ve thought of so far, but again, I am not sure if it’s the best/common way to accomplish this.

- User model has a ‘premium’ field which is either True or False
- Whenever user clicks on a premium-only API call, Django will check if user is premium or not to decide whether to make the actual API call. I currently have a '/user/me/' route which returns basic user information as API GET call.
- Upon successful stripe payment, stripe redirects user to the success_url. Then, somehow I will detect when user lands on success_url and then set that user’s premium field to True.

I know this is not the ideal way, because I already see lots of issues/hurdles:

How will I set ‘premium’ field back to False after user’s payment stops

- How can I ‘detect’ stripe’s payment to set user’s premium field
- Is this feature supposed to be implemented with Stripe customer objects instead? I would appreciate any guidance on where I should be looking for solutions.

Comment: This has little to do with Django and mostly with Stripe. There are many ways to integrate with Stripe; you can redirect to some of their forms and then let the user redirect back to your side, or you implement everything entirely on your side and use the Stripe API to set up payments. You can use Stripe's webhook feature to be notified of activity, e.g. failed payments or cancelled subscriptions, in which case you can unset the user's status. You can also simply periodically check the user's Stripe status via API calls to confirm whether they're still a paying customer.

Comment: @deceze When using webhooks, would that also notify me if transactions were successful? Because iirc success_url happens before payment is confirmed

Comment: Refer to all the events that you can subscribe to: https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/types

Answer (score 1):

If you use subscription on [Checkout Session (low code solution)](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/build-subscriptions?ui=checkout), you can add additional key-value pair data such as `premium: true` in [`metadata`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-metadata) and [`subscription_data.metadata`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-subscription_data-metadata) fields when creating a subscription.

Once the payment is completed, those metadata will appear in [`checkout.session.completed`](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/build-subscriptions?ui=checkout#provision-and-monitor) and [`customer.subscription.updated`](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/webhooks#events) webhook events, which you can then set the user as premium in your own database.

A customer object in Stripe can have multiple subscriptions, so this feature will be implemented on subscription object instead.